# Mercurial ignore the ".idea" folder form PyCharm?

Tags: django, mercurial, bitbucket, hgignore, pycharm

I am developing a Django app and it's my first time with Mercurial(using bitbucket).

I have done some commits without adding ".idea" folder from PyCharm to hgignore. Now I have added it to hgignore and want to remove .idea from the central repository but obviously do not want to delete the actual folder locally.

What's the proper way to handle this? I know this is a common thing, but I'm in the learning stage.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What it sounds like you want is for Mercurial to stop tracking everything under `.idea`. This should work (command issued in the repository root):

```
hg forget .idea\*
```

Comment: Bingo, that did it. Except when I used \* it has issues (I guess with character escaping). Thank you Joel.

Comment: Well, I'm on windows. It's possible that wouldn't work quite the same way on *nix since directory separators are `/` there.

Answer (score 4):

Use `hg forget .idea`. It's like `hg remove`, only it doesn't delete the file from your working directory.

Answer (score 3):

`hg forget .idea\*` should be your solution!

you could read up more on forget / remove here
http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html

just for reference you can delete the .idea folder. pycharm will generate it the next time you open up your project files using it.